# Wikipedia weird encoding answer for file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, wikipedia

```
<?php

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1');

echo file_get_contents('http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil', false, $context);

//echo file_get_contents('http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentina');

//echo file_get_contents('http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/France');
```

Wikipedia's answer is something like an encoding issue (I can't post it because StackOverflow post rules but you can see it if you run the script).

(etc.)

That's for Brazil and Argentina. But with other pages (like France) it works well. Any idea of whats happening? The pages works well with a browser, by the way.

Comment: What do you mean with "encoding issue"?

Comment: Please, don't impersonate browsers unless you really have to. With Wikipedia, you have to set the User-Agent to something, but it should be an informative string identifying you or your application. See [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

Comment: When I put it into a file, and try to open with less (Linux utility) I got:

"bla.txt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway? 

The content is impossible to read, all weird symbols (like a bad-encoded file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. I was receiving a gzip compressed HTML. I solved the problem using a php function to uncompress the HTML when the string appears to be binary.

I though cURL would handle the encryption in a transparent way for the developer, but I had the same problem. I think it's probably a Wikipedia issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this from console, make sure that it uses UTF-8 (should be so in Linux, not sure if it's possible at all in Windows).

If you're getting it from web, add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` to the beginning of your script to inform the browser of the correct encoding.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because when I send the content to a file, and try to open with less, I got:

"bla.txt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway? 

The weird thing is that this only happens with certain pages. I think it has something to do with a Wikipedia redirect, which applies only to certain pages.